# Rails 3 - tables in html.erb

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-3, html-table

I'd like to view data from different database-tables in a view with tables like this picture shows:[image]

I'm familiar with HTML tags `<table>`, `<td>` and `<tr>`, but I'm having trouble with multiple queries in a column.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Skills &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</th>
    <th>Expected-qualifications</th>
    <th>Current-qualifications</th>
  </tr>

   <% @employee.position.skills.each do |skill| %><% @employee.position.expected_qualifications.each do |expected_qualification| %><% @employee.current_qualifications.each do |current_qualification| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= skill.kategorien %></td>
    <td><%= expected_qualification.sollqualifikation %></td>
    <td><%= current_qualification.istqualifikation %></td>
  </tr>
  <% end %><% end %><% end %>

</table>
```

This code looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the skills, expected-qualifications, and current-qualifications repeat.

My question: How should the codes be ordered in the table so it will look the way I want it to?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try [zip](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001517):

```
<% @employee.position.skills.zip(@employee.position.expected_qualifications,@employee.current_qualifications).each |skill expected_qualification current_qualification| %>
<tr>
  <td><%= skill.kategorien %></td>
  <td><%= expected_qualification.sollqualifikation %></td>
  <td><%= current_qualification.istqualifikation %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: @ Sam Ruby: Thanks, that sounds logical, but I get an syntax error and I don't know why. I already tried to put the `@employee.position.skill (...)` into bracelets <% %>, but it still doesn't want to work, then it doesn't like the part `|skill expected_qualification current_qualification|`

Comment: @ Sam Ruby: Sorry, it still doesn't work. Rails still has some syntax problem with the counter. So it seems like it's not the right way to have 3 counters?

Answer (score 1):

if there is REALLY can be more than one `skill`, `expected_qualification` and `current_qualification` so you use `has_many` assosiation for`position`

```
<tr>
  <td><%= @employee.position.skills.map(&:kategorien).join(", ") %></td>
  <td><%= @employee.position.expected_qualifications.map(&:sollqualifikation).join(", ") %></td>
  <td><%= @employee.current_qualifications.map(&:istqualifikation).join(", ") %></td>
</tr>
```

Otherwise you should use `has_one` association

Comment: @ fl00r: a position has many skills and a skill belongs to many positions (e.g. both positions need to have driving license for building cran). And every combination of position and skills has an expected qualification. The current qualification is bend on the employee. Do I still need a has_one association? 

your code doesn't give any syntax error, but It doesn't execute the commands, it just shows it in the erb. Can it be that inside of <td> no code will be executed?

Comment: @Kirinriki, no it should be executed. And I've forget to close brackets.

Comment: @ fl00r: Thanks for noticing that the brackets are not closed. Now it says "NoMethodError", `undefined method current_qualifications' for "Position 1":Position`. sigh. Thanks anyways!

Comment: @Kirinriki, it should be `@employee.current_qualifications.map(&:istqualifikation).join(", ")`

Comment: @ fl00r: Great! Now it works. Thanks alot for your support. Now the data just needs to be viewed one below the other. Because right now it looks like this: http://img7.imagebanana.com/img/sa2gj098/skill.PNG

Comment: Ok, so you just follow @Sam Ruby approach, use `zip`, but there is a mistake, first line should look like this: `<% @employee.position.skills.zip(@employee.position.expected_qualifications,@employee.current_qualifications).each |skill, expected_qualification, current_qualification| %>`

Comment: jep, right. But I think, Rails has problems with the multiple counters, because it also doesn't work with commas in it. Furthermore, I already tried to seperate them like `|skill|, |expected_qualification|, |current_qualification|` but it also doesn't work. I really have no idea how solve this syntax problem :(

Comment: @Kirinriki, Rails works with this "counters" well. what error do you have got? what syntax error? show it

Comment: you've forget to add `do`: `<% @employee.position.skills.zip(@employee.position.expected_qualifications,@employ‌​ee.current_qualifications).each do |skill, expected_qualification, current_qualification| %>`