# HTML tables in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html-table

I'm creating a basic app to compare mortgage rates and have three models:

```
bank
  has_many :rates

rate
  belongs_to :bank
  belongs_to :term

term (i.e. the length the rate is valid for)
  has_many :rates
```

I've been attempting to output them into a basic html table that looks like https://i.stack.imgur.com/vC9xp.png however my code is not aligning the rates with the correct terms.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <% @terms.each do |term| %>
      <td><%= term.length %> months</td> 
    <% end %>
  </tr>

<% @banks.each do |bank| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= bank.name %></td> 
      <% bank.rates.each do |rate| %>
        <td><%= rate.rate %></td>
      <% end %> 
    <% end %>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How do I ensure that the rates are aligned with the terms they are valid for? The closest answer I've been able to find is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649758/rails-3-tables-in-html-erb) but it doesn't quite seem to do the trick. I'm also hoping to avoid using a gem to provide the functionality as I'm sure there must be a simple solution I'm missing.

Thanks in advance!

Edit 1:

I've now got this outputting what I was after, although it's pretty inefficient so I'm sure it could be tidied up a lot. The reason I'm having to select the rates out of the object array is that not every bank has a rate for a specific length so I can't just sort them into order and print them out. Any suggestions to improve the code are welcome!

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <% @terms.each do |term| %>
      <th><%= term.length %> months</th> 
    <% end %>
  </tr>
  <% @banks.each do |bank| %>
    <% @bank_rates = bank.rates.sort{ |a,b| a.term.length <=> b.term.length } %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= bank.name %></td>
    <td><% @rate = @bank_rates.select { |rate| rate.term.length == 0 } %><%= @rate[0].try(:rate) %></td>
    <td><% @rate = @bank_rates.select { |rate| rate.term.length == 6 } %><%= @rate[0].try(:rate) %></td>
    <td><% @rate = @bank_rates.select { |rate| rate.term.length == 12 } %><%= @rate[0].try(:rate) %></td>
    <td><% @rate = @bank_rates.select { |rate| rate.term.length == 18 } %><%= @rate[0].try(:rate) %></td>
  </tr> 
  <% end %> 
</table>
```

Comment: your `</tr>` should be inside the `<% @banks.each...%>` loop but you mis placed it you make it outside of that loop...look at my post it will be helpful to you what I want to tell you

Answer (score 0):

Use this gem for making tables its really nice and should do what you want [Wicegrid](https://github.com/leikind/wice_grid) and it can deal with associations , check the documentation on github

For example to make a table have index of users i made the following:

```
<div class="container">
  <%= grid(@users_grid, show_filters: :when_filtered) do |g|
    g.column name:  'ID', attribute: 'id', filter: false
    g.column name:  'Username', attribute: 'user_name'
    g.column name:  'First Name', attribute: 'first_name'
    g.column name:  'Last Name', attribute: 'last_name'
    g.column name:  'E-mail', attribute: 'email'
    g.column name:  'Role', attribute: 'name', model: 'Role' do |user|
      user.roles.collect{|role| role.name}.to_sentence
    end
    g.column name: 'Profile'  do |user|
      link_to('View', user_permissions_path(user))
    end
    g.column name: 'Edit' do |user|
      link_to('Update', edit_user_path(user))
    end
    g.column  do |user|
      if can? :destroy, user
       link_to('Delete', user, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'You sure?' })
    end
  end
  end -%>
  <% if can? :create, @user %>
  <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" onclick="location.href='/users/new';">Add new user</button>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look although I'm hoping to avoid using a gem as I'm sure there is a simple solution. I've edited the question to clarify.

Comment: well, it also gives you a nice view of your table and there is a filter option also and you can sort a column you may find it useful by the time

Answer (score 0):

Because your `</tr>` should be inside the loop but you make it outside

Look at my this section

```
 <% @banks.each do |bank| %>
 <tr> 
  <td><%= bank.name %></td>
 <% bank.rates.each do |rate| %>
   <td><%= rate.rate %></td>
 <% end %> 
 </tr>
<% end %>
```

you will get what I want to tell you and what mistake you did

```
<table>
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <% @terms.each do |term| %>
     <th><%= term.length %> months</th> 
   <% end %>
   </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <% @banks.each do |bank| %>
   <tr> 
    <td><%= bank.name %></td>
     <% bank.rates.each do |rate| %>
     <td><%= rate.rate %></td>
    <% end %> 
    </tr>
   <% end %>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Hope it will work...thanks

Comment: Thanks, thats not quite doing it though. Here's the html it generates

`<table>
  <thead>
   <tr>
     <th>0 months</th> 
     <th>6 months</th> 
     <th>12 months</th> 
     <th>18 months</th> 
   </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
   <tr> 
    <td>Bank 1</td>
     <td>5</td>
    </tr>
   <tr> 
    <td>Bank 2</td>
     <td>7</td>
    </tr>
   <tr> 
    <td>Bank 3</td>
     <td>6</td>
     <td>6</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>`

The problem is that it's outputting the rates directly after the bank, rather than relating them to the correct rate columns.

Comment: Here you go - http://imgur.com/YFW7cUQ. The problem is that the rates are printing directly after the bank, rather than relating to the term that they should.